# Получение текста элемента ListView [C#]

Tags: winforms, listview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить текст или хотя-бы индекс одного нажатого элемента списка. Нужно для удаления/создания следующей WF. Список состоит из одной колонки. Список динамически обновляется.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Notificator.Load.LoadPrev(listView1.SelectedItems.ToString());
            Program.prev.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `listView1.SelectedItems.ToString()` написать `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text`. Не?